# Azure Redis low performance reading Lists with “wide” 9K nchar strings

Tags: performance, redis

I’m testing Azure Redis performance on VM using StackExchange Client. All tests are done using WinForm app.

I have a test Azure SQL Server table “Test” with only one column ( nvarchar(max) ) and 1000 records. Each record contains random 9K nchar long text.
It was uploaded to Azure Redis as a List of 1000 items.

Now I’m trying to get all items by one RedisValue[] listValues= RedisDatabase.ListRange(key, 0, 999) call. 
I’m doing the same (SELECT * FROM Test and fill the Datatable) with Azure SQL Server. 
Surprisingly SQL call outperforms Redis call: 0.1 sec versus 2.5 sec.
Huge, unexpected and shocking difference.

I have a couple of questions:
1.  Am I doing something wrong?
2.  Problems with configuration?
3.  Azure Redis is not good?
4.  Azure Redis is not for long and “wide” lists?
5.  StackExchange is not the proper Client?
6.  Wrong API?
7.  Any other reason?

Note, that for shorter strings (below 100 char) Redis is the winner.

Comment: ListRange would perform at O(S+N) http://redis.io/commands/lrange. Depending on what you would like to achieve with the data retrieved you might consider using Hashes or Sorted Sets. http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set , http://redis.io/commands#hash

Comment: Here are more details on data type and their usage: http://redis.io/topics/data-types

Comment: Thanks, I saw this info already. This benchmark (O(S+N)) has nothing in common with the item's (string ) length. It assumes that time for retrieving whole 10 elements list, having 10x 1MB strings would be the same as for 10x 1byte strings which is incorrect.